# Show just one button when i check if at least one input is completed without show another button of the same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sap-commerce-cloud

I want create function when i put anything in inputs (i've 6), will show one button search and when fields are empty, the same button will be hidden.
Now, my problem is when i write, i get two button that i've declare in file .js and .jsp.(SEARCH and PROCEED).

I want a help just for this twice expressions:

```
<div class="button-row">
            <button class="btn btn-black" type="submit" name="search"><spring:theme code="multilogin.search.button"/></button>
        </div>
```

AND

```
<div class="button-row">
        <button class="btn btn-black" type="button" name="multiLogin"><spring:theme code="multilogin.button.login"/></button>
    </div>
```

You can find the code here --> https://jsfiddle.net/fm1y5c8v/1/

```js
inputField: function(){
       // $("#multiLogin-search input").on('input', function(){
                var showHideButtonSearch = () => {
                    let hasValue = false;
 $("#multiLogin-search input.text-input").each(function(){
                      if ($(this).val()) {
                        hasValue = true;
                      }
                    });
                    if (hasValue === false) {
                      $(".button-row").hide();
                    } else {
                      $(".button-row").show();
                    }
                }
                // Check input values on key up
  $("#multiLogin-search input.text-input").keyup(function() {
                   showHideButtonSearch();
                 });

                 //Hide button search on page load
                   showHideButtonSearch();
      // });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body> 


<form id="multiLogin-search" class="d-none">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
     <p> Customer number <p>
     <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="customerCode"  > <p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Country <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="country"  > <p>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Postal Code <p>
                    
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="postalCode"  > <p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Customer Name <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="customerName" > <p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> City <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="city" > <p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Address <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="address"><p>
                </div>
            </div>

            

<div class="button-row">
  <button class="btn btn-black" type="submit" name="search"><spring:theme code="multilogin.search.button"/></button>
            </div>
        </form>
        
    
        <div class="button-row">
    <button class="btn btn-black" type="button" name="multilogin"><spring:theme code="multilogin.search.button"/></button>
            </div>
 
        
</body>
</html>
```

thnx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do like that

```
if (hasValue === false) {
   $('button[name=search]').parent().hide();
} else {
   $('button[name=search]').parent().show();
}
```

Comment: Why you put .parent()?

Comment: in your example hide .button-row, it is parent block of your button, so i thought that you want to hide definitely it

Comment: Thank you very much. it's a best solution